# NDB MyModel.get_by_id() cannot find entity by key_name

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I'm implementing an OAuth2 authentication process.

I use a model called Client. First step, calling API to get request token, creating a client entity and temp store the token and secret in the client entity. Second step, after user authorise the app and redirect to the callback page... I need to get the same client entity and update the newly retrieved *access token* and secret.

In my first step, I have this:

```
key_name = 'service.%s' % (self.user.key.urlsafe(),)
client = Client.get_or_insert(
            key_name,
            parent=self.user.key,
            name='flickr',
            token=request_token['oauth_token'],
        )
```

And in my second step, I was trying to get the client by key_name:

```
key_name = 'service.%s' % (self.user.key.urlsafe(),)
client = Client.get_by_id(key_name)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot get the client in my second step... I tried to print out the string_id in step 1 and check against the key_name in step two, they were the same! But I still got None... I'm following the [cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic) method, correct me if I used the wrong method...

P.S. I'm actually connecting to Flickr, and if you have a better way of doing OAuth2, feel free to suggest as well! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the parent too

```
client = Client.get_by_id(key_name, parent=self.user.key)
```

edit why:

Since you put a parent in the insert means the get_by_id() just looks for the top level and you need to look for it in the correct group. You could also get it by key like:

```
client = ndb.Key(YourUserModel, userId, Client, key_name).get()
```

Comment: Faisal, thank you so much! And thank you for highlighting the reason behind! It saved my day!